# Nested Joins using Python pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies if the terminology is incorrect.

My Dataframe has 4 columns. 
Col1 is the personId (will hold multiples of the same value)
Col2 is the event type
Col3 is Boolean
Col4 is Boolean

Only col3 OR col4 can be true at any one time.

Input:

```
personId      EventType      Col3       Col4
1             A              True       False
2             A              True       False
3             A              True       False
2             B              False      True
4             A              True       False
3             B              False      True
```

Desired output:

```
personId      EventType      Col3       Col4      Col5
1             A              True       False     False
2             A              True       False     True
3             A              True       False     True
2             B              False      True      False
4             A              True       False     False
3             B              False      True      False
4             C              False      True      False
```

As you can see, Col5 will be true where the Trues from Col3 relate to a personId which has also had EventType B, but not C.

I am utterly stuck. I am sure I am overlooking something extremely simple.

I have tried the following:

```
df = pd.merge(df, left_on='personId', right_on='personId')


df = pd.merge(df, df[['personId','Col4']], on='personId', how='left)
```

but neither achieve the desired results.

Comment: I think you need to use `.loc` and `groupby` here, just to confirm `col5` is True only when a unique `personId` has had a True event type of B or C?

Comment: noticed that there is no event type C in the original dataframe. is that intentional?

Comment: Apologies I missed out the type C from the original data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better logic:

```
df['Col5'] = df.groupby('personId')['EventType'].transform(lambda x: (x=='B').any()) & df['Col3']
```

Output:

```
   personId EventType   Col3   Col4   Col5
0         1         A   True  False  False
1         2         A   True  False   True
2         3         A   True  False   True
3         2         B  False   True  False
4         4         A   True  False  False
5         3         B  False   True  False
```

Details:  Use groupby personid and `transform` EventType column to True if any Event in that personid equals to 'B', then use boolean logic operator and, `&` with 'col3'.

---

IIUC, you try using groupby and some boolean logic:

```
df.join(df.groupby('personId', group_keys=False)
          .apply(lambda x: (x['EventType']=='B').any() & x['Col3'])
          .rename('Col5'))
```

Output:

```
   personId EventType   Col3   Col4   Col5
0         1         A   True  False  False
1         2         A   True  False   True
2         3         A   True  False   True
3         2         B  False   True  False
4         4         A   True  False  False
5         3         B  False   True  False
```

Comment: Your simpler 'Better logic' answer got me the result I needed. The longer option didn't work for me as it didn't give me the extra column strangely enough.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to join, you need to set column 5 to be the XOR of column3 and column4

```
df['Col5'] = df['Col4'] ^ df['Col3']
```

Comment: Have you checked the desired output?

Comment: This wouldn't work as col5 is not XOR of col 3 and 4. Col 5 would ONLY be true if col3 was false and there was an additional true in Col4 for the same person ID.